# Replace symbol with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

Can i use str_replace to replace symbol?

Lets say i would want

```
<!-- Hello there -->
```

to

```
[Hello]
```

I might be easy for some, still learning str_replace and preg_replace

Comment: Answering your question: yes, you can.

Comment: try using the function twice

Comment: https://eval.in/166044 is it what u r looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass two arrays for the str_replace function. Example:

```
$find = array('<!-- ', ' there -->');
$replaceWith = array('[', ']');
$string = '<!-- Hello there -->';
$hello = str_replace($find, $replaceWith, $string);
```

Check the [doc](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through `preg_replace`,

```
<?php
$string = '<!-- Hello there How are you -->';
$pattern = "/^<!-- (\w+).*/i";
$replacement = '[$1]';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?> //=> [Hello]
```

It captures one or more word characters which are just after to `<!--`